Remove SaxonC-HE errors and warnings from stderr
I use SaxonC-HE library. When there is an error or a warning SaxonC sends the message in stderr.
Example of SaxonC error in stderr:
Error at char 17 in expression in xsl:variable/@select on line 1 column 356 
  FOJS0001  Invalid JSON input on line 2: Unexpected symbol: MyProduct
During lazy evaluation of fn:json-to-xml(...) on line 1 of 
  In template rule with match="/" on line 1 of 

I don't need that because I catch the SaxonC error with SaxonApiException. It pollutes my log file.
I would like to remove all SaxonC errors and warnings from stderr

Are you using the C++ API or the Python API or the PHP API of SaxonC? Anyway, I think it is the Java implementation of Saxon running in GraalVM that produces those outputs on stderr, will need to check whether there is some way for SaxonC to redirect or suppress them.

xsl:messages you should be able to capture in a file with Python https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc12/html/saxonc.html#PyXsltExecutable-set_save_xsl_message or C++ https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc12/html/classXsltExecutable.html#a736a57a3456aac14b363c1e8a60f7f1b

You could also try to set the configuration property STANDARD_­ERROR_­OUTPUT_­FILE (http://saxon.sf.net/feature/standardErrorOutputFile) to a file, that should redirect warnings and errors to that file instead of stderr.

At least from the SaxonC Python API it appears that the configuration property STANDARD_­ERROR_­OUTPUT_­FILE is not working as it works on the Java platform, a file is created but appears to remain empty, so I have filed a bug issue on that https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/6556

This issue of errors and waring going to stderr will be fixed in the next maintenance release. Thanks Martin for filing the bug issue regarding the error output file

I use  C++ API. I tried _xsltExecutable->setSaveXslMessage(false) and there is no impact. I tried standardErrorOutputFile="/tmp/saxon.log" and I received 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/tmp/saxon.log': I created the file before calling transformToString and I still have the error.

@JeromeGuillaume, I think O'Neil (@ond1) of Saxonica has commented that he has a fix to prevent errors and warnings going to stderr for the next maintenance release. As for the output file, my bug report mainly covers the Python API, feel free to add another one for the C++ API and the FileNotFoundException you get and I am sure the Saxonicans will look into it, if not already done. I doesn't look as if there is a workaround or solution for the current release, I am afraid.

Hi @JeromeGuillaume, Please can you send in code snippet which show us the problem. Also are you using the latest version of SaxonC 12.5?
